# complex coordinates of perpendicular chords on unit circle

Tags: complex-numbers, circles

I am faced with the following problem..

Consider three points $A (a), B (b), C(c)$ on the unit circle $|a|= |b|= |c|=1$. Find the complex coordinates of the point $D (d)$, where $D$ also lies on the unit circle & $AD \perp BC$.

Here's what I did:

By the first condition, $|d|=1$. We can think this like a cartesian coordinate system where the coordinates of $z$ are $ (\Re (x), \Im (x))$. So the perpendicular condition gives us $\frac{\Im (d)- \Im (a)}{\Re (d) - \Re (a)} \frac{\Im (b) - \Im (c)}{\Re (b) - \Re (c)}= -1$. But how do i continue from here? I am trying to find $d$ explicitly in terms of $a, b, c$. Expanding this looks huge.

Thanks.

Comment: no one?? :((((((

Comment: I considered rotating the vector BC by 90 degrees(multiply by i) to get the vector AD but I'm not sure this makes things less messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a point $D$ on $BC$ can be written as $d = (1-t)b + tc$ for some real number $t.$ now we will use the fact that $a$ and $b$ are orthogonal iff $a\bar b + \bar a b = 0.$ we need $t$ so that $AD$ is orthogonal to $BC,$ so

$$[(1-t)b + tc - a][\bar b-\bar c] + [(1 -t)\bar b + t \bar c - \bar a](b- c) = 0 $$

can you take it from here?

if you want the point $D$ on the circumference such that $AD$ and $BC$ are orthogonal then just use $$(a-d)(\bar b - \bar c) + (\bar a - \bar d)(b -c) = 0$$ and the fact that $\bar d = \frac{1}{d}$ to get a quadratic equation for $d.$

solving for $d$ you find $d = a, d = \dfrac{b - c}{a(\bar b - \bar c)}.$ the second is the you want.

check: suppose $a = i, b = -1, c = 1,$ then we know $d = -i.$ let us check the formula for $d = -2/(-2i) = -i$

Comment: But doesn't your method give the coordinates for the foot of perpendicular from A on BC? I am trying to find out the coordinates of the point where this perpendicular meets the unit circle. By the way, by your method I get $\frac{a+b+c}{2}$. I think your formula gives a good method though.. solve for $d$ where $|d|=1$ and $(d-a)\overline{(b-c)} + \overline{(d-a)}(b-c)=0$

Comment: thanks. i get $d= -bc/a$. Is this correct?

Comment: @hmhmhmhmhm, i have added the solution. i am not getting what you got.